# URL Validation Regex

Tags: php, regex, validation, url

As far as i know there are many other questions similar to title, but my main reason for asking this question is i want my validation as perfect as i want. Here is my explanation which URL should valid

`http://` (if given then match otherwise skip),
`domain.com` (should match & return validate)
`subdomain.domain.com` (should match & return validate)
`www.com` (should return false)
`http://www.com` (should return false)

I searched a lot about perfect regex pattern according to my need but didn't succeed so thats why i made my self and posting here to want to know that anyother Valid URL would it skip or not except http://localhost.
If yes then please correct me.

Pattern:

> ((?:http|https|ftp)://)?(?:www.)?((?!www)[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*(?:.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+):?(\d+)?/?

Comment: `http://` is optional in above regex

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are trying to match or not match that is different from most commonly available URL-matching expressions --  `www.com` and `http://www.com` are perfectly valid URLs and each go to a live website. Did you want to match `http://localhost`; do you want to match IP addresses? -- If you tell us what you are using this for, it may be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this actually doesn't answer your question directly, but REGEXes aside, you can also use [filter_var()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php), with the flag FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, which returns the URL in case of valid url, or FALSE otherwise:

```
   var_dump(filter_var('http://example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL));
   // string(18) http://example.com
```

You can read [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) the filters used by this function, especially the last row regarding flags used by the VALIDATE_URL filter.

I actually don't know how it's implemented internally, but I suppose it works better than many regexes you can find outside in the wild internet.

Comment: @Mr.Shan0 it doesnt anymore: http://codepad.viper-7.com/unRBvh - there *was* a [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51192) but it has been fixed since 5.2.14 and 5.3.3. Upgrade your php.

Comment: yeah i didn't notice that but `filter_var` allows `http://go` or `http://localhost` and my regex wont allow `http://localhost` as i said in my question.